# Different results from Mathematica than from Maple when solving an ODE numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, maple

I'm trying to solve this coupled ODE:

```
NDSolve[
  {B== 0, A == 0, ϕ[0] == 3.906*10^43, a[0] == 1, ϕ'[0] == 0},
  {ϕ, a}, {t, 0.0, 0.000001},
  StartingStepSize -> 1/100000000000,
  Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}];
Plot[Evaluate[{ϕ[t]}/. %], {t, 0, 1*10^-32}]
```

Where

```
A = 
  (a^′)[t] - 
    1.55613*10^-43 a[t] 
       Sqrt[
         (1 + 9.0808*10^-87 ϕ[t]^2)
         ((1-2.89051*10^-87 ϕ[t]^2)^2/1600000000000000000000+1/4 (ϕ^′)[t]^2)]
```

and

```
B = 
  -7.22627*10^-108 ϕ[t] (1-2.89051*10^-87 ϕ[t]^2) - 
  (3 ϕ[t] (a^′)[t]^2)/(4 a[t]^2 (1+9.0808*10^-87 ϕ[t]^2)^2) +
  (3 (a^′)[t] (ϕ^′)[t])/a[t]+(ϕ^′′)[t]
```

Using Maple I have the following plots;

[image]

(just black line for $\Phi$)

Using Mathematica, I have:

[image]

I don't have idea what is happening. I got these information:

```
Integration Method:  Fehlberg fourth-fifth order Runge-Kutta method with degree four of interpolation.

abserr = 1.10⁻⁸, relerr = 1.10⁻⁸
```

Comment: Your posted code have many syntax errors when I copied it to my notebook. Also you are using `b` which is not defined. It is better to paste code as plain text after changing it to InputForm. But without having the Maple code,  it is hard to answer this as the Maple code could have used some other options, or methods, etc....

Comment: Sorry, but "b" is defined, I just forgot to show it $ b = 3.906\times10^{43}$

Comment: Your initial condition is $\phi '(0)=0$ yet your Maple plot shows a clearly negative slope at $t=0$. So, I don't think your ODE matches up with what Maple computed.

Comment: The fact that your y-axis has such large numbers and your t axis has such small ones indicates to me that you should rescale your variables.

Comment: For reference, could you include the Maple code you used?

Comment: @J.M. I'm asking for it, as son as I get it I'll include the Maple code.

Comment: @J.M. I got these informations only:

Integration Method:  Fehlberg fourth-fifth order Runge-Kutta method with degree four of interpolation.

    abserr = 1.10⁻⁸, relerr = 1.10⁻⁸

Comment: It's generally a good idea to rescale your numbers to be around the order of magnitude of 1. Otherwise numerical solvers may make funny decisions about what differences are "small enough", and may consider your values effectively zero.

Comment: @Szablocs, I tried, but nothing changed... =\

Answer (score 1):

**Comment**

I tried with Maple, but I am unable to reproduce the results you have shown here. Nevertheless, the Maple results are in agreement with *Mathematica*.

```
restart:
with(plots):

eq1:=diff(a(t),t)-1.55613*10^(-43)*a(t)*sqrt((1 + 9.0808*10^(-87)*phi(t)^2)*((1-2.89051*10^(-87)*phi(t)^2)^2/1600000000000000000000+1/4*diff(phi(t),t)^2));

eq2:=-7.22627*10^(-108)*phi(t)*(1-2.89051*10^(-87)*phi(t)^2)-(3*phi(t)*diff(a(t),t)^2)/(4*a(t)^2*(1+9.0808*10^(-87)*(phi(t))^2)^2) +
  (3*diff(a(t),t)*diff(phi(t),t))/a(t)+diff(phi(t),t,t);

sol:=dsolve({eq1,eq2,phi(0)= 3.906*10^(43),a(0)=1, D(phi)(0)= 0},numeric);

odeplot(sol, [t, a(t)], 0.. 3*10^(-32),axes=boxed);
```

[image]

Comment: what was the integration mathod, the abserr and relerr values?

Comment: on Maple, the author have used rkf 4 − dae integration method.

Comment: @Kamog share source. Any link?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the Mathematica precision, using 30 digits I can get the correct plot.

[image]
[image]

The code:

```
NDSolve[{B == 0, A == 0, \[Phi][0] == 3.906*10^43, a[0] == 1, \[Phi]'[0] == 0}, 
{\[Phi], a}, {t, 0.0, 0.01}, StartingStepSize -> 1/1000, 
Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", Method ->
{"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}}]; Plot[Evaluate[{H} /. %], 
{t, 0, 0.1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

The (lame) trick was use more digits on my ODE:

```
A = Derivative[1][a][t] - (a[t] Sqrt[k^2 (1 + 2.9079917009173806522983649735*10^-87 \[Phi][t]^2)
(7.390838148960256000*10^151 (1-2.90799*10^-87 \[Phi][t]^2)^2 +1/2 Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]^2)])/Sqrt[3].

B = -8.596998400000002`*^65 \[Phi][t] (1 - 2.9079917009173815`*^-87 \[Phi][t]^2)-(3 \[Phi][t] Derivative[1][a][t]^2)
/(4 a[t]^2 (1+2.907991700917380652298364973524431895405957594617`28.88231157921247*^-87 \[Phi][t]^2)^2) + 
(3 Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t])/a[t] + (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]
```

Comment: Please include your *Mathematica* code and your *Maple* code.

Comment: Taking all of the real numbers to be exact, your system has an exact solution `phi=1.86*10^43, a=1`.  You can find that by setting all the derivatives to zero and solving algebraically.  I don't see how you get any of these plots. You should post code and verify that the posted code actually produces the claimed plots.

Comment: What I did was a lame trick, I just have copied  the values with 30 digits from maple to mathematica. Just it!